# How to target an id or class inside html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I came across with a problem that both "button" tag inside my page are being 
affected with the toggle.js dropdown effect.
So i decided to add an id to the first one so i can just call it in "toggle.js"
the problem now is i wasn't sure which one should i change inside the code(js)?
anyone knows how to target a button with id?

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyberjo50/awmd8/)

Here is the toggle.js

```
$(function () {
img_arrow = '<img src="images/down-arrow.png" width="20" height="20" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle; padding-top: 0px;margin-left:2px"/>';

var $window = $(window),
    $nav = $('nav'),
    $button = $('button');

$button.on('click', function () {
    $nav.slideToggle();
});

$window.on('resize', function () {
    if ($window.width() > 320) {
        $nav.show();
    }
});

$('#menu a').click(function (e) {
    $('button').html($(this).html() + img_arrow);

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is the HTML code for this? Maybe you can create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberjo50/awmd8/

Comment: i want the down arrow to flip to look like an up arrow when the menu is open. how to rotate the icon "images/down-arrow.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be `$("button#ID").on('click', function () ....`

**Edit:**

According to your fiddle, your button has a CLASS attribute, not ID.
So the above would be `$("button.submitButton").on('click' ...`

Or like commented below, you can simply have it as `$(".submitButton")...`, but I like to be accurate, just incase you have multiple elements with same class value.

Comment: Or just $('#ID') as the selector

Comment: I got it working now thank you guys.
Here is the code modified:
http://jsfiddle.net/cyberjo50/awmd8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use css syntax to select items using jQuery. Try    `$("#yourID").on('click', function())....`